# setForeground color in every component at one command java swing

Tags: swing

When i write:

```
jLabel1.setForeground(Color.Red);
jTextArea1.setForeground(Color.Red);
```

it works.
But i want to set this color at an one command.

Suppose i write setForeground(Color.Red), it will set for all the components.

Is it Possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can traverse through all components in a given container and invoke some operation (like color change) using the following code:

```
Component[] comps = yourPanel.getComponents();

for(Component comp : comps) {
    if(comp instanceof JComponent) {
       ((JComponent)comp).setForeground(Color.Red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. If that answer satisfies you, please accept it.